# TypeError: Could not guess image MIME subtype

Tags: python, gramex

I'm trying to capture the images of charts and attach them to the email template using the `img` tag. I'm able to send the email local but getting this `TypeError: Could not guess image MIME subtype` in the server.

I'm using Gramex capture API to capture the images and using email service in Gramex. When I checked in the server, the images are stored in the `png` format and right path. Not sure where the issue is.

Here's the code I'm using to capture and send the email.

```
def send_email(handler):
    user = handler.args.get('user', ['None'])[0]
    chart_selector = ['.bar-chart', '.donut-chart', '.world_map', '.headerImg']
    folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    mailer = service.email["galaxy-email-smtp"]
    try:
        yield service.threadpool.submit(
            load_file, user, chart_selector
        )
    except Exception as e:
        print("An error occurred:", str(e))
    temp_file = gc.open('email.digest.template.formatted.html', 'template')
    file_path_barchart = os.path.join(folder, 'downloaded1.png')
    file_path_donutchart = os.path.join(folder, 'downloaded2.png')
    file_path_worldmap = os.path.join(folder, 'downloaded3.png')
    file_path_header = os.path.join(folder, 'downloaded4.png')
    html_content = temp_file.generate(data={"handler": handler}).decode('utf-8')
    mailer.mail(
        sender=<email>,
        to=user,
        subject=<subject>,
        html=html_content,
        images={
            "headerImg": file_path_header,
            "ricoImg": os.path.join(folder, 'assets/img/rico.png'),
            "bar-chart-img": file_path_barchart,
            "donut-chart-img": file_path_donutchart,
            "world_map": file_path_worldmap,
        },
    )
    return "email has been sent"


def load_file(user, chart_selector):
    url = <url> + user
    for index, each_chart_selector in enumerate(chart_selector):
        file_name = f"downloaded{index+1}.png"  # Generate the file name
        chart_capture = capture.png(
            url, selector=each_chart_selector, scale=2, timeout=60
        )
        with open(file_name, "wb") as f:
            f.write(chart_capture)
```

Here's the traceback error:

```
ERROR   13-Jul 12:25:14 tornado.application:web Uncaught exception GET /send?user=<user>
HTTPServerRequest(protocol='https', host=<hostname>, method='GET', uri='/send?user=<user>, version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='59.160.48.210')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1704, in _execute
    result = await result
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 769, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gramex/handlers/functionhandler.py", line 53, in get
    item = yield item
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 762, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 775, in run
    yielded = self.gen.send(value)
  File "/mnt/apps/threat-research-email-digest/email_service.py", line 705, in email_digest_req
    mailer.mail(
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gramex/services/emailer.py", line 147, in mail
    msg = message(**kwargs)
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gramex/services/emailer.py", line 203, in message
    img = MIMEImage(handle.read())
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/email/mime/image.py", line 43, in __init__
    raise TypeError('Could not guess image MIME subtype')
TypeError: Could not guess image MIME subtype
```

Noticed that in Gramex `emailer.py`, we are not passing any `_subtype` value in the below code:

```
for name, path in images.items():
    with open(path, 'rb') as handle:
         img = MIMEImage(handle.read())
         img.add_header('Content-ID', f'<{name}>')
         html_part.attach(img)
```

When I tried giving a subtype in this line `img = MIMEImage(handle.read(), 'png')`, it is working fine. Is there any option to add the subtype in while adding images?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

See below, someone encountered the same issue and resolved it by declaring the subtype on the read/write method:
https://github.com/jakewaldron/PlexEmail/issues/6

Ex. `msgImage = MIMEImage(fp.read(),_subtype="png")`

OR

Ex. `msgImage = MIMEImage(fp.read(),_subtype=False)`